# Is there a way to extend multiple templates with resources in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have one pipeline that is referencing several templates with resources and I know you can extend a template with resources by using the `extend` keyword. I've been looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template-with-resources) documentation trying to make it work.

azure-pipeline.yaml

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repoName
      type: git
      name: project/repoName
    - repository: 'Release Notes'
      name: 'project/Release Notes'
      type: git
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ooi-adf-ci
      source: ooi-adf-ci

extends:
  - {template: '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-deploy-app-registration.yaml'}
  - {template: '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-set-app-credentials.yaml'}
  - {template: '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-buying-release-apps.yaml'}
  - {template: '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-buying-adf.yaml'}
```

I also tried something like:

```
extends:
  template:
    [
      '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-deploy-app-registration.yaml',
      '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-set-app-credentials.yaml',
      '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-buying-release-apps.yaml',
      '/cicd/pipelines/templates/stages-buying-adf.yaml',
    ]
```

template.yaml where the resource is consumed:

```
...
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ooi-adf-ci
      source: ooi-adf-ci
...
```

I get an error in my azure-pipeline.yaml file saying "A sequence was not expected". I'm wondering if this is actually possible as I haven't been able to find any documentation on it or if I'm just incorrectly doing it.

Comment: Did you solve the problem with multipale templates under one "extends"

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can infinitely extend templates at the root level, as in your example.

What you can do is compose a azure-pipeline.yaml file where each job / step is from a template. I do this a lot and works perfectly.

Here is the official docs:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insert-a-template)